# Add a role to an application to a resource group via PowerShell script

Tags: azure, roles, azure-resource-group, identity-management

I have a Resource Group 'test-rg'. How can I add a custom role 'Custom Role' to an application 'test-application' to this resource group via PowerShell script?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by

> "How can I add a custom role 'Custom Role' to an application 'test-application' to this resource group via PowerShell script?"

you actually mean:

> "How can I create a role assignment of the role 'Custom Role' for the application 'test-application' for a Resource Group by PowerShell?"

---

If that's the case, you need to just create a role assignment.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell
>
> Assign Azure roles using Azure PowerShell - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn

To do it in PowerShell, you need to run a following command:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <objectId> `
-RoleDefinitionName <roleName> `
-Scope /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<resourceGroupName>
```

Where:

- `<objectId>` is an Object ID of your Service Principal / Enterprise Application,
- `<roleName>` is a built-in or a custom role (e.g., `Custom Role`),
- `<subscriptionId>` and `<resourceGroupName>` are identifier of respective Subscription and Resource Group you want to give access to.

> Example:
>
> ```
> New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId "ae75b865-abf1-4376-afb8-54ebbf0b2051" `
> -RoleDefinitionName "Custom Role" `
> -Scope /subscriptions/4270e84b-c064-450b-9c67-a4a449d319df/resourcegroups/test-rg
> ```